# Dual U.S./canadian citizen living in Canada who has never resided in the U.S. can vote or not?

Tags: canada, citizenship, michigan

I am a Dual U.S./canadian citizen living in Canada who has never resided in the U.S. but my deceased mother lived and was born in Michigan and i was told i could register to vote but all Michigan voting sites states i must provide proof i lived in Michigan in order to vote?  true?

Comment: [This page](https://www.fvap.gov/citizen-voter/reside) lists the states where a US citizen who has never resided in the US can register to vote in the state where his/her parent last resided. This is allowed in only some states. Michigan is one of those states.

Answer (score 7):

[This document](https://www.michigan.gov/documents/sos/Military_overseas_manual_396041_7.pdf) from the Michigan Sec'y of State says that "A US citizen who has never resided in the US and has a parent, legal guardian or spouse that was last domiciled in Michigan is eligible to vote in Michigan as long as he or she has not registered or voted in another State". You then use the Federal Post Card Application or the Federal Write-In Absentee Ballot, which you can get [here](https://www.fvap.gov/).